# build tools on path

Tags: ruby

I'm not a programmer so be gentle with me.

I have installed Ruby and am now trying to install gems.  On a windows 7 machine I get the following error:

[image]

So I go to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and download and what I believe is install the tools based on what I understand from: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit but still get the same error.  This tells me I need to alter the path.  I know here the path is and how to alter it but I don't know what directory path needs to be added.  So two questions:

1. What do I put on the path?
2. Is what I'm doing sensible?

Comment: Try installing devkit from rubyinstaller.org

Comment: I recall you telling me you solved this.  You should post a solution if you know what you did.

Comment: A solution would be awesome.